# Hilt not detecting dependencies despite @Provides and @Inject

Tags: kotlin, dagger-hilt

I am practicing clean architecture in an app, so for this I divided the application in modules, App, data, domain. I have created the modules of the dependencies on the data module, where I have created the `UseCasesModule`. Such Module has been provided with the `@Module` tag and `@Installin(SingletonComponent::class)`, so on the App module I have added as a module dependency the Domain and Data modules. But when I am trying to inject the `UseCase` on the ViewModel I get the following error
`
com.example.usecases.GetUserByPersonaNameUseCase cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.

com.example.usecases.GetUserByPersonaNameUseCase is injected at
com.example.dota2stats.di.FactoryModule.providesHomeViewModelFactory(getUserByPersonaNameUseCase)`

This is not my first time with Hilt, so I know that I have to add the `@Provides` on the method that will provide the dependency, but right now is not working, I have restarted the app plenty of times. How can I solve this? Here my code

Here is the dependency

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class UseCasesModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun providesGetUserByPersonaNameUseCase(repository: Repository): GetUserByPersonaNameUseCase {
        return GetUserByPersonaNameUseCase(repository)
    }
}
```

Here the ViewModel where I am trying to inject it

```
class HomeViewModel (private val getUserByPersonaNameUseCase: GetUserByPersonaNameUseCase) : BaseViewModel() {
    
    override fun handleAction(action: Action): Flow<State> {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

}
```

I have tried by adding the @Inject constructor tag like this but still no results

```
class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor(private val getUserByPersonaNameUseCase: GetUserByPersonaNameUseCase) : BaseViewModel() {
    
    override fun handleAction(action: Action): Flow<State> {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```

Here the ViewModelFactory

```
class HomeViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(private val getUserByPersonaNameUseCase: GetUserByPersonaNameUseCase) :
    ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return HomeViewModel(getUserByPersonaNameUseCase) as T
    }
}
```

And here is how I am trying to use it

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var homeViewModelFactory: HomeViewModelFactory
    private lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        homeViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, homeViewModelFactory)[HomeViewModel::class.java]

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to annotate the ViewModel with @HiltViewModel?

```
@HiltViewModel
class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor(private val getUserByPersonaNameUseCase: GetUserByPersonaNameUseCase) : BaseViewModel() {
    
    override fun handleAction(action: Action): Flow<State> {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: yes I tried that too, but still not working